# Prove the sequence $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is monotonically increasing and bounded from above. USING INDUCTION

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Am I able to prove the monotonicity with induction?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I was able to prove it with induction, I just didnt know if you could use induction for an infinite sequece

Comment: Possible duplicate link doesn't contain any answer with induction, so it's not duplicate I think.

Comment: @JessSavoie If you have a proof by induction, then share it!  Why ask for a proof by induction when you already have one?